# Parsing redundant parenthesis while restoring input on non-committed failure

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have written a parser in Haskell's parsec library for a lisp-like language, and I would like to improve its error messages, but I am stuck in the following situation:

```
p :: Parser Integer
p = do
    try (string "number")
    space
    integer

parens :: Parser a -> Parser a
parens p = do
    char '('
    v <- p
    char ')'
    return v

finalParser p = p <|> (parens finalParser)
```

So the parser `p` behaves quite nicely error-wise, it does not commit and consume input until it sees the keyword "number". Once it successfully parsed the keyword, it will not restore its input on failure. If this parser is combined with other parsers using the `<|>` operator, and it parses the keyword, it will show the error message of `p` and not try the next parser.

Already `parens p` does not have this property anymore.

I would like to write a function `parens` as above that consumes only input, if the parser `p` consumes input.

Here are a few examples of the behavior, I am trying to achieve. finalParser should parse:

1. "(((number 5)))", "number 5", "(number 5)" all should parse to the integer 5, and consume everything,
2. "(5)" should consume nothing (not even the parenthesis) and fail
3. "(number abc)", "number cde" should fail and consume input.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to write a function `parens` as above that consumes only input, if the `parser p` consumes input.

Rather than that, consider factoring your syntax so you don't even need to backtrack after consuming a parenthesis.

Instead of trying to make this work:

```
parens p1 <|> parens p2
```

why not write this instead:

```
parens (p1 <|> p2)
```

?

Comment: Excellent! This could work! I was worried at first, since my parser p2 actually should parse things like "(eval a b)", where the brackets are essential. But finalParser (p1 <|> p2) will still take care of this correctly. The only example, where I get into trouble is if there a different kind of brackets involved, like ( ) for p1, and { } for p2, but that is quite contrived. Maybe from the way I think about the parsing these structures, I would prefer to have a <|> at the top-level, but I will definitely try this out.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot pull out finalParser all the way to the top, since I cannot move it past a sepEndBy1  between them.